# Google App Engine Python Authenticated Endpoints and Android

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine-python, android-authenticator

I'm not able to find a small example (or tutorial) of Android App (possibly with Android Studio) that use Authenticated Endpoints realized with GAE (possibly Python).

Google examples (Greetings and Tic Tac Toe) seems have some problem in my environment (token error, 404 not found, .....).

Can anyone help me? I'm going crazy...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access your Endpoint from api Explorer on localhost(http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer ) you can even simulate authentication there.

if API explorer is working then you need to check how you define SCOPE when getting credentials.

In my experience I had problems in following areas:
1. Generating Client IDs
2. define scoping in Endpoint API
3. Specifying correct scope in android App (server:client_id:123456789-abcdefghsadffwe.apps.googleusercontent.com";

Comment: Thank you Virtas for your reply. No problem in simulation (localhost or google cloud). And also points 1, 2 , 3 seems to be OK. But still do not works.

Comment: Can you show us: (1) your Android code you use to call endpoint and (2) your endpoint API definition

Comment: Dear Virtas, I prepared a simple version of my code... and now all it works! I do not understand my error, but now seems to be OK. Thanks again.

Comment: That's how I fix 80% of my issues. Once i start explaining to someone or preparing a simpler version of the code it starts to work

Answer (score 0):

I'm finally able to do it. 
I used this 2 google examples:

**On the server side:**
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-python

**On the client side:**
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-android

The instructions inside this pages are, in my opinion, better than the official google documentation.